# Фоновый поток (thread detach) перестает работать спустя час

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

`thread::join()` отработал 10 часов и продолжает работать. Но когда использую `detach()`, проходит от 50 минут до 1 час 10 минут, и поток останавливает работу.

```
std::thread thr1(waitSignal);
thr1.detach();
```

Что делаю не так?

**UPD**

```
void waitSignal(){
    while(1){
        std::ofstream log("/tmp/debug.txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out); 
        log << time << " - thread\n";
        sleep(10);
    }
}

int iniReceive(){
    // some code to start receive
    std::thread thr1(waitSignal);
    thr1.detach();
    return(1);
}

int main()
{
    iniReceive();
    while(1){
        printf("main");
        std::ofstream log("/tmp/debug.txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out); 
        log << time << " - MAIN\n";
        sleep(60);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: А что делает ваш основной поток? И как вы понимаете что он перестаёт рабоать. Приведите пожалуйста весь код.

Comment: Перестает работать потому, что перестает писать время в файл. Тогда как основной поток продолжает записывать текущие время в файл.

Comment: Какой компилятор используется? Для начала я бы рекомендовал вынести объект `log` из цикла, чтобы не выполнять создание/уничтожение на каждой итерации, и использовать **разные** файлы. Может быть имеет место проблема с одновременным доступом к файлу из разных потоков.

Comment: Использую Eclipse. 
Начал использовать файл чтобы конкретно отследить проблему. До этого вместо записи в файл мигал светодиодом когда работал параллельный поток, но он также переставал мигать через час.

Comment: Eclipse - это среда разработки, а не компилятор...

Answer (score 3):

Мне жутко не нравятся две вещи - что
1. используется один и тот же файл, при этом
2. он простаивает в открытом состоянии все время. Вы бы хотя бы закрывали его перед вызовом `sleep`, что ли... а еще лучше - "обсемафорили" мьютексом...

И потом, при `join()` ваш основной поток к файлу не лезет, ждет завершения... а при `detach()` они работают параллельно - начинаются коллизии. То, что вы наблюдаете, может быть простым голоданием - потому что основной поток тоже держит файл постоянно открытым, закрывая лишь на время вывода `printf("main");`.

Comment: Начал использовать файл чтобы конкретно отследить проблему. До этого вместо записи в файл мигал светодиодом когда работал параллельный поток, но он также переставал мигать через час.

Comment: Попробуйте все же запустить вот такой код - http://vpaste.net/15tqZ - и расскажите потом, пожалуйста, как результаты...

Comment: Понять, почему не мигает светодиод при полном отсутствии информации, как и почему он мигает - это же совсем другая задача. Я отвечаю вам на задачу, поставленную в вашем вопросе. А светодиод - откуда же мне знать ("да как же тебя понимать-то, коли ты ничего не говоришь?" (с) Иван Васильевич, поменявший профессию... :))

Comment: "До этого вместо записи в файл мигал светодиодом когда работал параллельный поток" а вы на каком устройстве запускаете, если можете мигать светодиодом?

Comment: 17:07:50
 - main
17:08:20
 - main
17:08:25
 - main
17:08:30
 - main
17:08:35
 - main
17:08:40
 - main
17:09:25
 - main
17:10:00
 - main
17:10:05
 - main
17:10:10
 - main

Comment: Поставил задержку 5 сек, но как видим иногда задержка основного потока 30 сек

Comment: Что-то у вас не видно "thread", только "main"?